# Change behavior of tableview inside custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped tableview (A) that contains a custom cell that contains a tableview (B).
I'm trying to modify the standard behavior of the tableview B so that when it is at y=0 and I drag it toward the bottom, the grouped tableview (A) scrolls instead of the tableview B.
In other words, when the tableview B element is at y=0 I want to disable its scrolling and even if I drag touching it, I want the grouped tableview (A) to scroll.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a `UITableView` in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @ismailgulek That's what it looks like to me. :(

Comment: wut? May be a better way is using a UICollectionView and inside it put a UITableView, but i'm not sure if is it possible

Comment: @giuseppef4 That's weird enough. Did you try setting your tableview B's `scrollEnabled` to `NO` when you don't want it to be scrolled (maybe you should implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method for your tableview A).

Comment: This is possible. You'll need to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method scrollViewDidScroll: in the implementation file that's set as your outer table view's delegate/datasource. From there, set up your own delegate (or other method) to notify the inner table of the content offset changes. Then all you have to to is fiddle with the content offsets of the two tables to prevent the outer from continuing to scroll while passing the changes to the inner table instead.